# Question regarding integration over smooth $0$-manifolds

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-geometry, orientation

Let $\mathcal M := [a, b]$, this is a smooth manifold with boundary $\partial\mathcal M = \{a,b\}$. Let $f \in C^\infty(\mathcal M)$, then for any smooth $0$-manifold $N$, $$\int_Nf :=\sum_{p\in N}\pm f(p)$$ where the positive sign is taken when the orientation is positive and the negative sign where it is negative. We can use Stokes' theorem to get the following result: $$\int_\mathcal Mdf =\int_{\partial\mathcal M}f= (\pm f(a)) + (\pm f(b))$$ which should  give us the result $f(b) -f(a)$, in order to recover the fundamental theorem of calculus. My question is: how do we determine the orientation of $\partial \mathcal M$ in order to get the desired result? Can $\partial \mathcal M$ be consistently oriented?

Comment: Orientation of a manifold induces an orientation of it's boundary.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, I know this, but different points can have different orientations in a $0$-manifold, how is this a consistent orientation?

Comment: Tell us the boundary orientation definition ….

Comment: @TedShifrin given an outward pointing vector field $X$ and an orientation form $\omega$ for $\mathcal M$, the boundary orientation form is given by $\iota^*(i_X (\omega))$, where $\iota:\partial \mathcal M \to \mathcal M$ is inclusion and $i$ is interior multiplication.

Comment: So what does this say when you apply it to the compact $1$-manifold with boundary $[a,b]$?

Comment: You get a smooth function that takes the value $-1$ at $a$ and $1$ at $b$. How then can we consider this as a consistent orientation?

Comment: How do you test consistency? You look at small connected subsets.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your statement. Wouldn't the orientation be consistent if each point was oriented in the same way?

Comment: Consistency is local, not global. You can’t break your own global definition and retort “but it’s locally consistent.”

Comment: How then do we define a consistent orientation? As one that has the same orientation (i.e. positive or negative) on each connected component?